# Feeding output of <p:xslt> into <c:body> of HTTP PUT request in Xproc

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xquery, xproc

My goal for my Xproc pipeline below is to take in a source XML document, run 2 XSLT transforms with `<p:xslt>` steps, then feed the output XML after the 2nd `<p:xslt>` to the `<c:body>` of the `<p:http-request>` step:

```
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step"
    version="1.0">

  <p:input port="source" primary="true"/>
  <p:output port="result" primary="true"/>

  <p:serialization port="result" 
                   indent="false" 
                   method="xml" 
                   encoding="utf-8" 
                   omit-xml-declaration="false"
                   doctype-system="myDTD.dtd" 
                   doctype-public="-//DOCTYPE-HERE"/>

  <p:xslt>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
      <p:document href="XSLT-1.xslt"/>
    </p:input>
  </p:xslt>

  <p:xslt>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
      <p:document href="XSLT-2.xslt"/>
    </p:input>
  </p:xslt>

  <p:http-request omit-xml-declaration="false" 
                  encoding="UTF-8">
    <p:input port="source">
      <p:inline>
        <c:request href="http://localhost:80/myRESTserver/dburi/myDOC.xml" 
                   auth-method="basic" 
                   username="user" 
                   password="admin" 
                   method="put">
          <c:body content-type="text/xml" >

          </c:body>
        </c:request>
      </p:inline>
    </p:input>
  </p:http-request>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? When I try executing this code as is, the `<p:http-request>` is invoked first (PUTS an empty XML file into the database).

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `p:http-request` runs first is that it does not depend on any other steps in the pipeline. The `source` input port of `p:http-request` is bound to a static inline `c:request` document and therefore the step does not need to wait for any other steps to finish first. The step can therefore run at any time.

To fix that, you need to connect the input port of `p:http-request` to the second `p:xslt` step. This can be done explicitly (using `p:pipe`) or implicitly (relying on the fact that the XProc processor will manufacture implied `p:pipe` connections automatically). Let's demonstrate both while solving your main question (embedding the output of `p:xslt` in `c:body`) in the process:

For embedding XML content in XML wrappers, the usual go-to XProc steps are `p:wrap` and `p:wrap-sequence`. However, they work with simple (one level) XML wrapper elements, so they are not all that helpful if you want to wrap in multiple levels of XML (as in your case: `c:request/c:body`). So you have to use something else - for example the `p:insert` step:

```
...
<p:xslt name="xslt2">
  <p:input port="stylesheet">
    <p:document href="XSLT-2.xslt"/>
  </p:input>
</p:xslt>
<p:insert match="c:request/c:body" position="first-child">
  <p:input port="source">
    <p:inline>
      <c:request href="http://localhost:80/myRESTserver/dburi/myDOC.xml" 
                 auth-method="basic" 
                 username="user" 
                 password="admin" 
                 method="put">
        <c:body content-type="text/xml">
        </c:body>
      </c:request>
    </p:inline>
  </p:input>
  <p:input port="insertion">
    <p:pipe step="xslt2" port="result"/>
  </p:input>
</p:insert>
<p:http-request omit-xml-declaration="false"
                encoding="UTF-8"/>
...
```

Let's take a look at what this does:

1. We gave the second `p:xslt` step a name (`xslt2`).
2. We placed an `p:identity` step in between the second `p:xslt` step and the `p:http-request` step. The `p:identity` step uses a static `c:request/c:body` document as the insertion target and the output of the step named `xslt2` as the content to be inserted. It inserts the content as the first child of `c:request/c:body`.
3. We removed the static connection from the `source` input port of the `p:http-request`. This is fine because the output of the `p:insert` step will flow into the `source` input port of `p:http-request` automatically.

Comment: is the C:Request taken out of the P:http-request and placed inside the p:insert step? Right now Xproc is saying that p:insert cannot contain a c:request

Comment: Yes, the `c:request` is taken out of the `p:http-request`. You get the error because I forgot to wrap the `c:request` in a `p:inline` - I just fixed that in my post.

Comment: @VojtěchToman I have a similar use case (but with an `http-request` step followed by an `xquery` step, then another `http-request`). When I try to add the `p:insert` step, as suggested, I get an error (in XML Calabash) saying, "Expression could not be evaluated: Prefix c has not been declared." Where should the prefix be declared?

Comment: @tat: You can most likely declare it on the element that uses the `c:` prefix, or on any of the ancestor elements. The root element where you probably declare the other XProc namespace prefixes should be a good place, too. The namespace declaration should look as follows: `xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step"`

Comment: @VojtěchToman This may be an issue with the Calabash Piperack Web service, since the pipeline works in Calabash on the command line (namespace declared on `declare-step` root).